# RecyclerView not scrolling smooth after loading huge amount of data

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I have hug amount of data coming from sqlite database .After loading data and showing it in recyclerview then the recyclerview does not scroll smooth.
So how to increase the performance of recyclerview.

Comment: Please provide your Adapter code

Comment: You should care about an item itself, `RecyclerView` takes care of huge amount of data (it only displays a few, say 7 of them at a time). So, the problem in your case may be, for example, huge image in each row, or heavy calculation in each `onBindViewHolder`.